# AppGyver: Can't open two modals in succession in a supersonic app

Tags: steroids

I am trying to open two views in succession, both as modals in an Appgyver project. when i do `supersonic.ui.modal.hide()` and `supersonic.ui.modal.show(some_view)`, the second view does not show. If I throw in an `alert('here')` in between the `modal.hide()` and `modal.show()`, it seems to work. What is the problem here? It's the same with `supsersonic.ui.layers.pop()` and `supersonic.ui.layers.push(another_view)` in succession.

Usage sample:

```
}else if (option === 'chooseLocation'){
  $scope.currentOption = "location you chose.";
  $scope.f = true;
  supersonic.ui.modal.hide().then(function(){
    supersonic.ui.modal.show("chooseLocation");
    $localStorage.locationOption = 'lastUsed';
  });
}
```

another snippet that i tried this morning that's not related to modals, but also doesn't work:

```
supersonic.ui.layers.popAll().then(function(){
  var view = new supersonic.ui.View("searchresults#index?"+paramText);
  supersonic.ui.layers.push(view);
});
```

The error I get on the log screen:

```
landing#drawer  11:23:29.382    error   
"supersonic.ui.layers.popAll rejected: {}"
```

Comment: Could you share the full code example? My guess is that you're invoking the second function call before the first one has been executed successfully. You should invoke the second modal.show in the promise's success callback.

Comment: @peter updated the question to include an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the Supersonic API.

The Javascript success callback is invoked when the native wrapper has received the API call. This is invalid behaviour. The Javascript success callback should be invoked when the native wrapper has *completed* the API call (expected behaviour).

As a workaround, use Use Steroids.js events such as `didclose` to determine when the native API call has completed.
See [Steroids modals](http://docs.appgyver.com/en/edge/steroids_Steroids%20UI%20Components_Steroids.modal_modal.on.md.html) and [Steroids layers](http://docs.appgyver.com/en/edge/steroids_Steroids%20Views_Steroids.layers_layers.on.md.html#steroids.layers.on) for further documentation.

I have filed a new bug in [AppGyver Github issues](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/739)

Comment: Is `steroids` defined? You must include steroids.js if it's not. PS. It sounds like you're not using Safari Inspector / Chrome DevTools to debug the problem.

Comment: yes, `steroids` is included in `common#layout`. I am on linux, and it says my OS is not supported to use the chromeDevtool.